# Error while Installing moodle 3.0.3+

Tags: plugins, installation, moodle

the problem I think is because I retried installation of moodle on the same database, when I remembred that I did'nt create another database I just deleted all its tables and redo the installation but it gives me these errors.

PS: I tried to edit the file config.php, I did'nt find it, apparently Moodle did'nt create it while the installation ( I don't know if it means that there is a problem or not)

```
Debug info: Error code: codingerror
Stack trace:
line 2675 of /message/lib.php: coding_exception thrown
line 2722 of /message/lib.php: call to get_message_processor()
line 356 of /lib/messagelib.php: call to translate_message_default_setting()
line 313 of /lib/messagelib.php: call to       message_set_default_message_preference() 
line 532 of /lib/upgradelib.php: call to message_update_processors()
line 1647 of /lib/upgradelib.php: call to upgrade_plugins()
line 677 of /admin/index.php: call to upgrade_noncore()
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to create config.php, there is a sample in the root directory called config-dist.php https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Configuration_file

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.

I restarted from scratch (another database, and imported a new moodle project in my hoste site) , I started installation and after the first step (I added the database name, user password..) submit and they tell me : 

Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: Default theme clean not available or broken!

I really don't know.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much,
I made an error while installing moodle, since I reinstall it everything is okay now. 
For the problem of default theme I didn't have the file config.php in the folder moodle/theme/clean I added it and the problem is resolved. 
Thank you again :)